# .NET List Thread-Safe Implementation Suggestion needed

Tags: .net, list, thread-safety

.Net List class isn't thread safe. I hope to achieve the minimal lock needed and yet still fulfilling the requirement such that as for reading, phantom record is allowed, and for writing, they must be thread-safe so there won't be any lost updates.

So I have something like

```
public static List<string> list = new List<string>();

In Methods that have **List.Add**/**List.Remove** , I always lock to assure thread safety

            lock (lockHelper)
            {
                    list.Add(obj);
                    or list.Remove(obj);
            }

In Methods that requires **List Reading** I don't care about phantom record so I go ahead to read without any locking. In this case. Return a bool by checking whether a string had been added.

          if (list.Count() != 0) {
              return list.Contains("some string")
          }
```

All I did was locking write accesses, and allow read accesses to go through without any locking. Is my thread safety idea valid?

I understand there is List size expansion. Will it be ok? My guess is that when a List is expanding, it may uses a temp. list. This is ok becasue the temp list size will always have a boundary, and .Net class is well implemented, ie. there shouldn't be any indexOutOfBound or circular reference problems when reading was caught in updates.

Comment: which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not safe. You should protect against reads and enumerations.

Since you are using 4.0, check out the new thread safe collections.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

Comment: If I use my own impl. of enumeration instead of the one provided by .net (which threws exception when the list had been modified) like this one.  http://refactormycode.com/codes/945-cached-ienumerable-t
Will it now be thread-safe?

Comment: its a lot of extra work, especially since .net gives you these now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Framework 4; Why not use [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using .NET 4.0 you should just use the `ConcurrentBag<T>` as it provides as threadsafe implementation of an UnorderedList.

You can see all the Thread-Safe Collections here

[.NET Thread Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)